# Send Grades Using Google Classroom's API to Power Teacher Gradebook

Tags: google-classroom, powerschool

With the new Google Classroom API is there a way to integrate directly with an SIS like Power Teacher, to send grades directly from Google Classroom to Power Teacher?  I know we can download and upload into PT, but this is a bit much form some teachers.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. As far as I know, the Classroom API doesn't have any methods to handle the grades or any functionality for the courses (like questions or assignments). https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/

Answer (score 2):

The Classroom API doesn't currently give access to the assignments, so the answer is currently no. However, I imagine Google is working on it, so the answer probably won't be the same in a few months.

The bigger problem is that the Classroom assignments model is extremely simplistic. It's much more like a Facebook wall posting than what SISes would typically require. So, to have an automated direct connection between the two would likely only work for simple cases of assignments. However, when Classroom gets there, it would probably be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Today Google released new APIs to access Google Classroom grades and more elements inside assignments. I hope PowerSchool will build functionality now to export from Classroom to PowerTeacher Gradebook
https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework#adding_attachments_to_a_student_response